# Access to dynamically added files from different project under same solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, path, solution

So I have 2 different projects inside the same solution like this:

```
Project1

Project2
   SomeFolder
      SomePicture1.jpg
      SomePicture2.jpg
```

The pictures inside the project2 are added dynamically from what the user is uploading. My question is, can I do something like `<img src="Project2/SomeFolder/Somepicture1.jpg" />` inside Project1? I know I can set the path (link) to where Project2 will be hosted in the web.config but when deploying to the production servers I need to change these links and I would like to avoid doing this.
There is reference from Project1 to Project2.